# Pressure formula with infinitesimals

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics

I'm studing classical physics and i'm stuck with the simple pressure formula defined as:

$P=\frac{dF_{\perp }}{dS}$

Now, i know some calculus and the concept of infinitesimal in physics; however what i dont understand is :

**according with the fact that $dF_{\perp }$ represent an infinitesimal change, it's an infinitesimal change from which quantity ?**

Comment: It isn't a change in anything. It is a small amount of something.

Comment: If we obtain that the pressure is a constant, this means that the dF decreases as i take smaller dS . Why the force is depends on the surface ?

Comment: If presure is constant then dF is proportional to dS. Smaller surface, smaller force.

Comment: Why mathematically Force varies with surface ? It's function of surface ? I ask this because the simply formula P=dF/dS doesnt give me these information

Comment: Sorry I do not understand what your difficulty is.